# Browser Acting Weird with PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a php script where I use `$_SESSION` to store logged in users datas.

Today, I noticed while testing the script logging-in/logging-out using multiple accounts ,(I don't know how this is related) I started getting `MYSQL Import.php errors` in my `phpMyAdmin` and it even effected me logging in to my web server provider ticketing system.

How I noticed this? after searching for hours on what's causing this `MYSQL Import.php errors` I accidentally logged into my `phpMyAdmin` from another machine, it shockingly, was working just fine! as soon as I started using my script to login , I started getting these `MYSQL` errors again.

**How am I using `Global Sessions`?**

- Inserting `session_start()` in all pages where I need my session variables.
- When a user logs out, I first call `session_unset()`  then
  `session_destroy()`
- I noticed that `session.save.path` is set to `/tmp/` but when
  I check `phpinfo()` it says `no value` .

**This is a screen shot of how my `/tmp/` folder containing the sessions (it keeps increasing and decreasing):**
[image]

Comment: Sounds to be like your browser or operating system has got itself confused. Can you reproduce the problem after rebooting?

Comment: Yes! even after rebooting my Mac.

Comment: Are you running your script on the same domain as you are running phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is running on my server obviously, and website is hosted on same server. So if I get your question correct , yes.

Comment: Can you post the URL's with which you use phpMyAdmin and your own code?